# EMR kill PIG script

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, apache-pig, cluster-computing, emr

Is there a way of killing a running pig script, not only the current hadoop job ?

As you know a pig script is translated to a hadoop job DAG. Assume everything runs smoothly up to some point in this graph but, for some reason, I want to stop the execution of this script/"DAG". Is there an emr command to do that ?

I tried to kill the current hadoop job and it looks like the execution of the pig script is CANCELLED but the cluster/master node is left in a weird state which makes all the subsequent pig scripts fail instantly.

Comment: Did you listed the jobs (hadoop job -list) and tried to kill by the jobid (hadoop job -kill $jobId) ?